# Variable exchange?

Tags: ruby

```
@current_engine, engine_was = engine.to_sym, @current_engine
```

how can I interpret this expression or advise please where I can find the definition of this kind of expression, initially I thought there swapping values

Comment: The answers explain how parallel assignment can be used to swap values (as here), but it's sometimes used in a more mundane way: `a, b = 1, 2`, resulting in `a => 1, b => 2`.  Some like this, others don't.  Personally, I reserve parallel assignment for swaping.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: good note, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's so called "parallel assignment" (now you can google it). It's more or less equivalent to this:

```
_a = engine.to_sym
_b = @current_engine
@current_engine = _a
engine_was = _b
```

First, values on the right side are evaluated and then they are assigned. That's why you can also use this trick to swap values:

```
x, y = y, x
```

When `y` will be assigned value of `x`, it will use old value, which it held at the beginning of this expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand this into the three steps:

1. Creation of an array from:

   ```
   a = engine.to_sym, @current_engine
   # => [ 1, 0 ]
   ```
2. Assignment the array to a left side of expression.
3. Expanding the array into the specified vars:

   ```
   @current_engine = a[ 0 ]
   engine_was = a[ 1 ]
   ```